# Magento site not showing product images and main banner

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, product-images, full-page-cache, banner-slider

I have recently moved my client site arabianglitz.com to a new hosting and using magento 1.9.2.4 in it.

For cache using a full page cache and maxcdn as well. As the site was moved to a new hosting full page cache ask me to setup a cron job which I did via cpanel.

Now my client site main home page banners and all product images are gone...

Help needed.

Comment: Have you migrated the `media` directory to the new server? Did you set the correct permission `755` for the media directory?

Comment: yes but its 777- should I set it up to 755?

Comment: Yes its 755 now but still no luck with this error

Comment: is it also possible that this could be a scripts.js issue:

scripts.js:201 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).vide is not a function
scripts.js:580 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).unveil is not a function

Comment: Yes, a possibility is there, but make sure you can access your image via direct url

Comment: URL is not showing as well :(

Kindly check my client site: arabianglitz.com

Comment: The url retrurned is magento's place holder url. You need to check whether the images are available or not. Try to flush your CDN cache as well

Comment: Error fixed, there was another extension which was recently installed on magento. After deleting all files of that extension and clearing up cache its working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error fixed, there was another extension which was recently installed on magento. After deleting all files of that extension and clearing up cache its working fine now.